# How to convert between character and byte position in Objective-C/C/C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, utf-8, nsstring

I need to convert from a byte position in a UTF-8 string to the corresponding character position in Objective-C.  I'm sure there must be a library to do this, but I cannot find one - does anyone  (though obviously any C or C++ library would do the job here).

I realise that I could truncate the UTF-8 string at the required character, convert that to an NSString, then read the length of the NSString to get my answer, but that seems like a somewhat hacky solution to a problem that can be solved quite simply with a small FSM in C.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Loop over the string with `mblen`.

Comment: @n.m.: That's not enough, since `NSString` uses UTF-16 offsets.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: NSString does not have a role here.

Comment: @n.m.: `NSString` is mentioned twice in the question and it's in the tags too.  The `NSString` documentation does not use the same terminology for characters and positions as the Unicode standard, which is a shame, but I doubt the question is about counting code points.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: it is mentioned there as a part of a method the poster considers inappropriate. It is not in the requirements.

Comment: @n.m.: The poster considers it inappropriate, but correct.  In cases where the poster describes a problem one way but gives a contradictory example, you need some way to disambiguate.  This is tagged `objective-c`, and if you use the same terminology as Apple’s documentation, then there is no contradiction.

Comment: @n.m.: This is off-topic, but the reason examples are so important in questions is because it is so common for people with technical problems to use terminology in an unclear or ambiguous manner.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: the term 'character' is defined, in one sense, as a basic unit of encoding, and in this sense characters are isomorphic to code points. If the poster wants characters in some other sense, then a lot more work would be required.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: the question is also tagged C and C++, which do not necessarily have an apple flavour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Character" is a somewhat ambiguous term, it means something different in different contexts.  I'm guessing that you want the same result as your example, `[NSString length]`.

The `NSString` documentation isn't exactly upfront about this, but `[NSString length]` counts the number of *UTF-16 code units* in the string.  So U+0000..U+FFFF count as one each, but U+10000..U+10FFFF count as two each.  And don't split surrogate pairs!

You can count the number of UTF-16 code points based on the leading byte of each UTF-8 character.  The trailing bytes use a disjoint set of values so you don't need to track *any* state at all, except your position in the string (good news: a finite state machine is overkill).

```
static const unsigned char BYTE_WIDTHS[256] = {
    // 1-byte: 0xxxxxxx
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
    // Trailing: 10xxxxxx
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    // 2-byte leading: 110xxxxx
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
    // 3-byte leading: 1110xxxx
    // 4-byte leading: 11110xxx
    // invalid: 11111xxx
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
};

size_t utf8_utf16width(const unsigned char *string, size_t len)
{
    size_t i, utf16len = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        utf16len += BYTE_WIDTHS[string[i]];
    return utf16len;
}
```

The table is 1 for the 1-byte, 2-byte, and 3-byte UTF-8 leading characters, and 2 for the 4-byte UTF-8 leading characters because those will end up as two characters when translated to `NSString`.

I generated the table in Haskell with:

```
elems $ listArray (0,256) (repeat 0) //
    [(n,1) | n <- ([0x00..0x7f] ++ [0xc0..0xdf] ++ [0xe0..0xef])] //
    [(n,2) | n <- [0xf0..0xf7]]
```

Comment: Is the above solution correct even when (1) char is signed, not unsigned, and (2) a byte is not 8 bits (i.e. `CHAR_BIT != 8`)?  The second issue can probably be ignored for most modern applications; I'm not aware of any modern platform with `CHAR_BIT != 8`.  But the second issue seems a bit more worrisome, since then the `char`s returned by `string[i]` with their high bit set will be interpreted as a negative offset into `BYTE_WIDTHS`, no?

Comment: Ah, regarding point #1, never mind; I was thinking in terms of `std::string`, which returns `char` from `operator[]`, but your function is written in terms of a `const unsigned char *` parameter, so that is irrelevant.  I'm still curious about point #2, though; how does all this work when a byte is not 8 bits?  Does the UTF-8 standard assume 8-bit bytes?

Comment: @bhaller: `CHAR_BIT` is irrelevant for two reasons.  #1: `CHAR_BIT != 8` is so *incredibly rare* that it is basically pointless to talk about. You might as well be talking about having unicorns write your code. #2: If `CHAR_BIT != 8` then values >= 256 are still impermissible in UTF-8.  The Unicode standard doesn't "assume" 8-bit bytes, it simply defines the term "byte" to mean an 8-bit integer.  This does not mean you can't use Unicode on a system where `CHAR_BIT != 8`, it just means that the Unicode standard and the C standard have a different definition for byte on that platform.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [UTF-8 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) and note that code points begin with the following 8-bit patterns:

```
76543210 <- bit
0xxxxxxx <- ASCII chars
110xxxxx \
1110xxxx  } <- more byte(s) (of form 10xxxxxx) follow
11110xxx /
```

That's what you should look for when searching for the beginning of a code point.

But that alone is only a part of the solution. You need to take into account [Combining characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks). You need to take combining diacritical marks together with the main character that precedes them, you cannot just separate them and treat as independent characters.

There's probably even more to it.

Comment: Even more, the `NSString` API counts UTF-16 code units, not code points.  So you will need to count the `11110xxx` bytes as two.  Also note that your diagram is from a defunct version of UTF-8, the current standard stops at `11110xxx` (`111110xx` and `1111110x` are invalid).

Comment: @DietrichEpp Thanks, I've removed the last two.